# How to delete documents in a collection with the same key value in Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection and each document in the collection has a key titled "group_id".
I want to delete all documents that have the same value assigned to group_id. How do I do this?

Below is a screenshot of one of these documents. Notice the group_id key in the image.

[image]

I can delete individual documents and iterate through collections, but I am having trouble combining these two things to iterate and delete the documents that I want to delete.

**Delete a singdocument**

```
export async function deleteCalendarEventFromFirebase(authenticatedUsersUid, id) {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(authenticatedUsersUid).collection('calendar_events')
    return snapshot.doc(id).delete();
}
```

**Iterate and get a collection**

```
export async function getClientCalendarEventsFromFirebase(authenticatedUsersUid,clientID) {
    const snapshot = await   firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(authenticatedUsersUid).collection('calendar_events').where("client_id", "==", clientID).get();
        return snapshot.docs.map((val) => {
            let dataObj = val.data()
            dataObj.id = val.id;
            return dataObj
        })

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect the promises from each document's delete, convert that into a single promise with Promise.all(), and make sure the final promise doesn't resolve until all the documents are deleted.  It helps to understand what all is actually in a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).

```
export async function yourFunction(authenticatedUsersUid,clientID) {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(authenticatedUsersUid)
        .collection('calendar_events')
        .where("client_id", "==", clientID)
        .get();

    await Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.delete()));
}
```